# Flutter (Dart>=2.0) with OrientDB

Tags: firebase, neo4j, flutter, orientdb, orientdb3.0

I was wondering is it possible to make Flutter running on Dart >= 2.0 work with a graph database backend solution like Orient DB? I searched on the web and the Dart package available both for Neo4j and OrientDB work only on Flutter running on Dart 1.0 [https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/orientdb_dart and https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/neo4j_dart]. However, I am on the stable Flutter channel and it uses  a greater version of Dart.

I am stuck because I have been learning Orient DB and Neo4j for months as I developed my app in Flutter and I need to find no easy implementation of Flutter with graph databases. My app requires a non-relational model thus SQlite is out of the question. Firebase is Nosql and is a good alternative but I have never used it and it would mean learning a new database solution.

Is there a work around to make Flutter work with the graph solutions? It seems rather biased towards Firebase for a Nosql implementation but not everyone wants a Firebase backend. Graphs are very good solutions for highly connected data which my App depends on, I have spent too many hours on graphs to just throw them down the drain in the name of Firebase because Flutter doesn't have support for them. Is there a work-around with Flutter and Orient DB?